# list out owned file/directories and change its permissions

Tags: unix, permissions, chmod, aix

Can anyone please tell how can I change files/directories owned by me only.

below is the command that list out files/directories owned by me

```
 find . -user <username>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -user olduser -exec chown newuser:newuser -- {} . \;
```

You may need to switch to root user or use sudo before chown

Comment: Too many args to exec? What is the purpose of the dot?

Comment: Now that you mention it, I have always used it, but it works without...

Comment: The dot does something you may not intend since it changes the owner of the current directory every time.